# Is there anyway to keep threads alive and assign different tasks to thread when needed - Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to create 10 threads for our Java application and keep them alive all the time. These 10 threads should be alive all the time and run the tasks I assign to them. The tasks I'm trying to assign them are the file downloads, report downloads, and PDF downloads.

I tried to let keep them alive by asking them to sleep all the time and interrupt them when assigning new tasks to them. However, those file generation are based on different parameters in our system so that I cannot define my file generating logic in InterruptedException exception catch block. I'm curiouse whether there's a way to interrupt the threads and assign them different tasks(functions) in classes that don't extends thread or implement runable interface?

I created 10 threads sleeping all the time, and add them to a public static arraylist.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS_DOWNLOAD; i ++) {
    Thread tempT = new Thread() {
        public void run(){
            Thread.currentThread().setName(BriString.value(WebServer.getThreadIndex()));
            while (true) {
                try {
                    sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //DYNAMIC LOGIC OF FILE/REPORT/PDF GENERATION
                }
            }
        }
    };
    tempT.start();
    DOWNLOAD_THREAD_POOL.add(tempT);
}
```

Below is the code that I tried to access the threads alive and wants to add the logic there.

```
for (int i = 0; i < WebServer.DOWNLOAD_THREAD_POOL.size(); i++) {
    Thread tempT = WebServer.DOWNLOAD_THREAD_POOL.get(i);
    String currentName = tempT.getName().replaceAll("\\D+","");
    if (tempT.isAlive()) {
        tempT.interrupt();
        // TRYING TO ADD THE FORM/FILE/PDF GENERATION LOGIC HERE
        // ONCE TASK AS FINISHED BY 1 THREAD, WE EXIST FINDING THE THREAD AVAILABLE
        break;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the Thread Pools provided by Java?

Comment: Isn't thread startup and teardown light enough to make the task abstraction desirable for a better understanding of the implementation of a feature (e.g., file, report, pdf downloads)? Why not have a thread runner defined for each?

Comment: you could look at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)

Comment: You should be using an `Executor`, not manual thread management.

Comment: Ditto other comments: There's a name for an object that keeps a number of threads alive and waiting for tasks to perform. It's called a [_thread pool_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool). The Java standard library provides an interface for thread pool-like objects, [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), and it provides a versatile implementation of that interface, [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/java-thread-pool-executor-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern Java we rarely need to address `Thread` class directly. Instead we use the [Executors framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) to mange threads on our behalf.

> I'm trying to create 10 threads for our Java application

If you are confident that 10 threads is appropriate for your work load on your deployment computers, then simple create [an executor service backed by ten threads](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)).

```
ExecuterService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 ) ;
```

By the way, if [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) succeeds, even this judgement on your part will likely go away. The new [*virtual threads*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8277131) (fibers) will be so “cheap” that we can have thousands, even millions, of threads running at a time. And these virtual threads will all be new and fresh, with no need to recycle them in a pool. Experimental builds with *Project Loom* technology are available now, based on early-access Java 18.

```
ExecuterService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() ;
```

> keep them alive all the time

No need for that. Let the executor service manage its backing thread pool.

> run the tasks I assign to them.

Define your task as either a `Runnable` or a `Callable`.

```
Runnable weeklyReportTask = () -> WeeklyReport :: generate ;
```

Submit an instance of your task to the executor service.

```
executorService.submit( weeklyReportTask ) ;
```

> The tasks I'm trying to assign them are the file downloads, report downloads, and PDF downloads.

Just keep on submitting tasks. The executor service takes care of juggling task assignments to the threads in its backing thread pool.

```
executorService.submit( fileDownloadTask ) ;
executorService.submit( weeklyReportTask ) ;
executorService.submit( pdfDownloadTask ) ;
```

> However, those file generation are based on different parameters in our system so that I cannot define my file generating logic in InterruptedException exception catch block. I'm curiouse whether there's a way to interrupt the threads and assign them different tasks(functions) in classes that don't extends thread or implement runable interface?

Define your task as an instance of a class of your own design that implements `Runnable` and carries a `run` method. Put a constructor on your task class that takes arguments for those different parameters that affect your file generating logic. Pass the arguments when instantiating your task object. Then submit the task instance to your executor service.

Your `Runnable` implementation then contains all the information it needs to do its job. No need to interrupt threads; no need to even know about any threads specifically.

All of this has been addressed many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Re, "We rarely need to [instantiate] `Thread` class directly." That's true when the problem calls for a thread _pool,_ but a thread pool is not the best answer to _every_ need for threads. Some applications need one or more _long running_ threads that (each) await events from a particular external source and deal with those events in a particular way. Of course you can use pool workers for that purpose, but directly instantiating `Thread` or using a `ThreadFactory` makes the program a bit simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: ...But yeah! The OP wants a thread _pool_. (I.e., wants an ExecutorService.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow I suspect the virtual threads & `Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()` of *Project Loom* that I mentioned in the Answer will eventually be the solution to your case of long-running threads awaiting an event, while relieving us of the chore of managing any `Thread` object.